# Sending data from one domain to another through websockets

Tags: node.js, socket.io, emit

I'm using Socket.IO to attempt to transfer information from one domain to another... is that possible?

I want to send data upon a `POST` request to one domain to another domain...

I have a successful connection on the receiving end, but am having trouble with the sending end.  Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. According to socketio documentation, it is possible to make cross domain connections irrespective of the browser.

[http://automattic.github.io/socket.io/#faq]

You can directly connect to the server ( sending end ) from the client via **io.connect** and there is nothing special you have to do in the server side code.

This link may be helpful in handling POST requests. http://showmetheco.de/articles/2011/8/socket-io-for-backend-developers.html

Also, it would be really nice if you can post what kind of issue you are running in to in the sending side.